How can I tell whether an object is obscured by other objects?
I'm trying to detect if an object is visible for the camera on the scene below:

The object is behind the wall but my code always returns true (visible).
I'm using this code to detect it:
bool isTargetCollisionFree = Physics.Linecast(mainCamera.transform.position, target.transform.position);

Am I doing something wrong?
Both objects have box colliders and are on same Default layer.
Camera object doesn't have a collider.

Physics.Linecast: Returns true if there is any collider intersecting the line between start and end.
